# What could be causing Javascript to stop working in IE in Strict mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I'm trying to debug my jQuery plugin and it worked fine in IE until I added `<!doctype html>`. It still works fine in all browsers except IE  *sigh* (tested in 6,7,8). What sort of thing could be causing this?

here is the page: http://liime.net/projects/liimeBar/demo.html

Comment: What do you mean by "strict mode" exactly and what doesn't work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Pekka: the inverse of what's been called *quirks mode* ;) "Almost standards compliance mode" comes closest.

Comment: I can't tell what doesn't work on your page.  Please describe the EXACT steps you take and describe WHAT doesn't work.  Please remember - we don't know your site or how anything is supposed to work so unless you tell us, we don't know what is and isn't working.

Comment: Does IE give any indication of an error other than just not working? The little yellow triangle and exclamation point in the status bar can sometimes point you in one direction or another as far as where the problem is.

Comment: This isn't an improvement on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600001/problems-with-html-doctype-and-javascript-in-ie), which was closed. You haven't described any issue other than to say it isn't working, and there's nothing here that could be useful to a future reader (especially after your demo page is gone).

Comment: Well I'm not getting any errors although looking at the interpreted source I can see in IE6 the elements are being added to the DOM as it should be but in 7 and 8 nothing is happening and for some reason in IE7 there is a browser scroll bar even though I have overflow set to hidden!

Comment: Why don't you try and theme a jQuery UI slider?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll

Comment: I am not implying this is a fix, it's just something I noticed about your site, you do not define charset in either your page or HTTP headers. IE acts poorly with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in constructScrollers()
window.innerHeight < $('body')[0].scrollHeight
is false, bacause both values are the same in IE8.
So no scrollers are created

Do some research in jQuery that you find the proper function how to get the heights you want to test.

You have much code in it, that could be better if you used more jQuery functions, not just the selectors.

--edit
try this instead
$(window).height() < $('body').height()

P.S.: By this script you can only make a scrollbar for the body, because you hard coded the body. try $(this) instead, which is the object you called your liimebar() function with and don't use ids on liimebar_buttons, ..bar etc, but classes, so you could possibly have more than on scrollbar.

Comment: Yeah I am a bit of a jQuery noob. I will try my best to improve!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I just realized in IE window.Height works after the DOM has loaded (Don't see how seeing as the point of the ready function is to prevent the script executing until after the DOM has loaded, right?). I coded this to be used with the body only then when I feel up to it I will make it so it works on every element in the DOM which needs a scroll bar (as I said I'm pretty new to javascript/jQuery and programing in general). Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: No prob.If your question is answered than click answered, so other people see it